# Google V3 API - File Upload to a Shared Drive

Tags: google-api

We are trying to use Google V3 API in Snaplogic to upload a file to Google Drive shared drive. When we use both `parents` and `driveId` parameter in the request, we are getting `404` error.

We tried the same payload with and without `supportsAllDrives` but, we see the same issue.

```
[
{
"response":
{
"statusLine":
{
"protoVersion": "HTTP/1.1"
"statusCode": 200
"reasonPhrase": "OK"
}
"entity": "No Content"
"headers":
{
"content-length": "0"
"vary":
"X-Origin"
"alt-svc":
"h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43""
"cache-control":
"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
"x-guploader-uploadid": "Test Upload ID"
"pragma":
"no-cache"
"content-type":
"text/plain; charset=utf-8"
"server":
"UploadServer"
"date": "Thu, 24 Jun 2021 05:01:58 GMT"
"location": "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable&upload_id=testuploadid"
"expires": "Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT"
}
}
"original":
{
"name":
"drivetestfile.txt"
"driveId": "SharedDriveID"
"parents": ["FolderID inside Shared Drive"]
}
}
]
```

However, when we just use `parents` with a shared folder (not in drive but, under user home) the files are getting uploaded without any issues.

Any of the inputs on this issue will really help us.